# Publishing scene does not make planner take it into account

Tags: ros, rviz, ompl-planning, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm working with a model of the schunk 7DOF arm in moveit. I import objects into the environment and publish the scene but still the planner provides a path that goes through the object. I get the sense that the planning pipeline and rviz are not communicating on the same topic.

How do I find out and fix it?

Thanks much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90021/publishing-scene-does-not-make-planner-take-it-into-account/) by [Chipper10](https://answers.ros.org/users/7401/chipper10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out the issue was using the joint state publisher gui to set the goal configuration. Path planning worked fine if the final configuration was set from rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Chipper10](https://answers.ros.org/users/7401/chipper10/) with karma: 41 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-12**:
Good you came back and dropped an answer for others!